# Download jsonarray file express, node, angular

Tags: node.js, json, angular, express, http-headers

In a webapp I'm doing, there are jsonarray files that are created. For example, they look like:

```
[{attr1:"123",attr2:"456"},{attr1:"abc",attr2:"def"}]
```

I am trying to send these jsonarray files to the client and they should be downloaded exactly as they in the server, they should not be opened or parsed.

In express I have tried using, `send`, `sendFile` and `download`

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.json');

res.sendFile(name, function (err) {
    if (err) {
         console.log('error sending:', name, err);
    } else {
         console.log('Sent:', name);
    }
});
```

in the front end I am using file-saver

```
this.Service.get(filename).subscribe(
    result => {
        console.log(result)
        let blob = new Blob(result, {type: "application/json"});
        saveAs(blob, collectionname+".json");
    }
);
```

and when i open the file in the client it looks like this:

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

But then I console.log() the result, I see the json objects.

What can I do?

---

Versions of my setup:
Angular CLI: 12.0.5
Node: 14.16.1
Package Manager: npm 7.11.1
Angular: 12.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob cannot take json objects as argument (not even array of json objects).
You could pass an array of strings, e.g.

```js
new Blob(result.map(x=>JSON.stringify(x)), {type: "application/text"});
```

Raed the [Blob documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) for details.

Comment: Interesting, sadly I don't get the objects inside an array, but at least now I get the content. Thank you!